# Fresh cluster and linkerd - viz doesn't startup

Tags: kubernetes, servicemesh, linkerd

I've got an issue, I'm trying to install linkerd on my cluster, all is going well

I went exactly with this official README

```sh
https://linkerd.io/2.11/tasks/install-helm/
```

installed it via helm

```sh
MacBook-Pro-6% helm list -n default
NAME        NAMESPACE   REVISION    UPDATED                                 STATUS      CHART           APP VERSION
linkerd2    default     1           2021-12-15 15:47:10.823551 +0100 CET    deployed    linkerd2-2.11.1 stable-2.11.1
```

linkerd itself works, and the `linkerd check` command as well

```sh
MacBook-Pro-6% linkerd version
Client version: stable-2.11.1
Server version: stable-2.11.1
```

but when I try to install `viz` dashboard as described in the [getting-started](https://linkerd.io/2.11/getting-started/) page I run

```sh
linkerd viz install | kubectl apply -f -
```

and when going with

```sh
linkerd check
...
Status check results are √

Linkerd extensions checks
=========================
/ Running viz extension check
```

and it keeps on checking the viz extensions, and when I ran `linkerd dashboard` (deprecated I know) shows the same error

```sh
Waiting for linkerd-viz extension to become available
```

anyone got any clue what I'm doing wrong ? Been stuck at this part for 2hrs &_& and noone seem to have any answers

note, when I ran, `linkerd check` after instalation of viz I get

```sh
linkerd-viz
-----------
√ linkerd-viz Namespace exists
√ linkerd-viz ClusterRoles exist
√ linkerd-viz ClusterRoleBindings exist
√ tap API server has valid cert
√ tap API server cert is valid for at least 60 days
‼ tap API service is running
    FailedDiscoveryCheck: failing or missing response from https://10.190.101.142:8089/apis/tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1: Get "https://10.190.101.142:8089/apis/tap.linkerd.io/v1alpha1": net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
    see https://linkerd.io/2.11/checks/#l5d-tap-api for hints
‼ linkerd-viz pods are injected
    could not find proxy container for grafana-8d54d5f6d-cv7q5 pod
    see https://linkerd.io/2.11/checks/#l5d-viz-pods-injection for hints
√ viz extension pods are running
× viz extension proxies are healthy
    No "linkerd-proxy" containers found in the "linkerd" namespace
    see https://linkerd.io/2.11/checks/#l5d-viz-proxy-healthy for hints
```

---

debugging

Comment: What kind of cluster are you using? Can you share the output from `kubectl get po -n linkerd-viz`? I'd also look at `kubectl get ev -n linkerd-viz --sort-by="{.lastTimestamp}"`

Comment: Definitely need more info to fully understand what is happening here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your problem descripiton:

> ‼ linkerd-viz pods are injected
> could not find proxy container for grafana-8d54d5f6d-cv7q5 pod
> see https://linkerd.io/2.11/checks/#l5d-viz-pods-injection for hints

and:

> MacBook-Pro-6% helm list -n default

I encountered a similar problem but with `flagger` pod rather than `grafana` pod (I didn't attempt to install `grafana` component like you did).

A side effect of my problem is this:

```
$ linkerd viz dashboard
Waiting for linkerd-viz extension to become available
Waiting for linkerd-viz extension to become available
Waiting for linkerd-viz extension to become available
... ## repeating for 5 minutes or so before popping up the dashboard in browser.
```

The cause for my problem turned out to be that I installed the `viz` extension into the `linkerd` namespace. It should belong to the `linkerd-viz` namespace.

Looking at your original problem description, it seems that you installed the control plane into the `default` namespace (as opposed to the `linkerd` namespace.) While you can use any namespace you want, the control plane must be in a separate namespace from the `viz` extension. Details can be seen in the discussion I wrote here:

- https://github.com/linkerd/website/issues/1309